# Deleting image from list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my text field

```
<input type="file" name="noteMedia[]" multiple id="ssi-upload" />
```

Variables

```
const dT = new DataTransfer();
const fileInput = document.getElementById("ssi-upload");
```

I'm adding copy and paste feature, so i do this

```
document.onpaste = function(event){
  var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
  const dTLocal = new DataTransfer();
  for (index in items) {
    var item = items[index];
    if (item.kind === 'file') {
      var blob = item.getAsFile();
      var reader = new FileReader();
      dTLocal.items.add(blob);
      fileInput.files = dTLocal.files;
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }
  }
  $("#ssi-upload").change();
  i=i+1
}
```

and here is my `#ssi-upload.change()`

```
 $("#ssi-upload").change(function(){
      $("#imagePreview").html("");
      var file =  $(this)[0].files[0];
      dT.items.add(file);
      fileInput.files = dT.files;
      imageIndex = 0;
      Array.from(dT.items).forEach(item => {
        var blob = item.getAsFile();
          var image = new Image()
          var reader = new FileReader();
          var uri = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          var img = new Image();
          img.src = uri;
          var imagePreview = "<img width = '150px' height='100px' src='"+uri+"'>";
          $("#imagePreview").append('<td style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">'+imagePreview+'<p class="text-center" align="text-center"> <a onclick="return deleteImage('+imageIndex+');" href="#"> Delete </a></p> </td>');
          imageIndex = imageIndex + 1
        });
       
    });
```

So i want to have two ways to adding file, copy paste and default way from the input field. So, the problem is when i'm trying to delete the item `deleteImage`

```
 function deleteImage(index){
      const fileListArr = Array.from(fileInput.files)
      fileListArr.splice(index, 1)
      $("#ssi-upload").change()
    }
```

The result is instead of remove file it is adding another file. So, how can i fix it ?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cekytg5L/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `$("#ssi-upload").change()` and add class to `td` like `img-preview` and pass `this` params to `deleteImage` so you can access that element. check the snippet below.

```js
const dT = new DataTransfer();
const fileInput = document.getElementById("ssi-upload");

var i = 0;
let imageIndex = 0;
document.onpaste = function(event){
    var items = (event.clipboardData || event.originalEvent.clipboardData).items;
    const dTLocal = new DataTransfer();
    for (index in items) {
        var item = items[index];
        if (item.kind === 'file') {
            var blob = item.getAsFile();
            var reader = new FileReader();
            dTLocal.items.add(blob);
            fileInput.files = dTLocal.files;
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        }
    }
    $("#ssi-upload").change();
    i=i+1
}

$("#ssi-upload").change(function(){

    $("#imagePreview").html("");
    var file =  $(this)[0].files[0];
    dT.items.add(file);
    fileInput.files = dT.files;
    imageIndex = 0;
    
    Array.from(dT.items).forEach(item => {
        var blob = item.getAsFile();
        var image = new Image()
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var uri = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = uri;
        var imagePreview = "<img width = '150px' height='100px' src='"+uri+"'>";
        
        $("#imagePreview").append('<td class="img-preview" style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">'+imagePreview+'<p class="text-center" align="text-center"> <a onclick="return deleteImage('+imageIndex+',this);" href="#"> Delete </a></p> </td>');
        imageIndex = imageIndex + 1
    });
   
});

function deleteImage(index,obj){
    const fileListArr = Array.from(fileInput.files)
    fileListArr.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(fileListArr);
    $(obj).closest('.img-preview').remove();
    //$("#ssi-upload").change()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="noteMedia[]" multiple id="ssi-upload" />
<table class="table" id="imagePreview"><tbody></tbody></table>
```

Comment: thank you now i can delete the image without error, but when i copy another file the deleted file showing up again.

Comment: What do you mean by copy another file?

Comment: copy and paste new file

Comment: can you create a snippet with a copy and paste example?